# cordova qrscanner reduce camera view

Tags: reactjs, cordova, cordova-plugins, qr-code

For cordova plugin: cordova-plugin-qrscanner, I know that the default camera view is full screen.

Can I **reduce the camera view size**? Like the following picture

[image]

So that **only the upper screen can be used** for the qr code scanning.